# How to show braintree user interface in codename one

Tags: codenameone

How do I display the UI of the braintree in codename one?  I only  have this code `

```
Purchase.startOrder(new Purchase.Callback() {
    public String fetchToken() {



    }

    public void onPurchaseSuccess(String nonce) {

    }

    public void onPurchaseFail(String errorMessage) {

    }

    public void onPurchaseCancel() {

    }
});`
```

pls, I need a guide here. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `startOrder` will show the UI implicitly on the device once you implement the server side functionality that returns the token.

To test this in a mockup go to the [braintree getting started guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/android/v2) you will notice code that looks like this:

```
public void onBraintreeSubmit(View v) {
  DropInRequest dropInRequest = new DropInRequest()
      .clientToken("long-token-string-that-looks-like-gibberish");
  startActivityForResult(dropInRequest.getIntent(this), REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

You can use that token for debugging some of the process. Notice that price etc. are all determined in the server to prevent tampering so the token includes all of that data. I'd place the debug token here but I'm not sure if this is something that expires/changes.

Comment: You are doing a great job for developers here. Kudos to you the founder of codenameone. More grease to your elbow. Your guide really helpful. Thanks